# On the meaning of Continuous Mapping Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces, weak-convergence

In the context of a lecture on mathematical statistics we got the following result we called

> **Continous Mapping Theorem** (CMT):
>
> Let $h:(S,d) \to (S',d')$ be $\mathfrak{B}_d(S)$ - $\mathfrak{B}_d'(S')$ measurable. Where $(S,d)$,$(S',d')$ are metric spaces and $\mathfrak{B}_d(S)$,$\mathfrak{B}_d'(S')$ their respective Borel $\sigma$-algebras. Further let $D_h := \{x \in S | h$ not continuous in $x\}$ then the following hold:
>
> 1. $P_n \overset{w}{\longrightarrow} P$ and $P(D_h)= 0$ $\Longrightarrow$ $P_n \circ h^{-1} \overset{w}{\longrightarrow}P \circ h^{-1} $
> 2. $X_n \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} X$ in $(S,d)$ and $P(X \in D_h)= 0$ $\Longrightarrow$ $h(X_n) \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} h(X)$ in $(S',d')$
> 3. Let h be continuous. Then $X_n \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} X$ in $(S,d)$ $\Longrightarrow$ $h(X_n) \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} h(X)$ in $(S',d')$

My interpretation is this:
Generally speaking CMT states that measurable functions between metric spaces that are continuous or at least almost surely continuous preserve convergence in distribution for random variables on their domain.

For 1. my understanding is a bit more hazy: Sequences of probability measures that converge for arguments in $\mathfrak{B}_d'(S')$ also converge applied to the preimages (under $h$) of those arguments.

We used CMT for part of the proof of the

> **Cramér-Wold-Device**: The following are equivalent
>
> a) $X_n \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} X$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$
>
> b)$\forall t \in \mathbb{R}^d$:  $\langle t, X_n \rangle \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} \langle t, X \rangle$ in $\mathbb{R}$

where $a) \Longrightarrow b)$ follows directly because for all $t \in \mathbb{R}^d$ the scalar product $x \mapsto \langle t, x \rangle$ is continuous and hence $b)$ follows with the CMT.

I put this down mostly to sort my mind on the issue. But I would much appreciate opinions on the meaning or intuition of the CMT and also other examples for its uses. Have a great day!